# Search Design Pattern

Tags: jakarta-ee, search, design-patterns, architecture, uml

I'm doing a design for a search functionality. I identified that there is a generic "Search" use-case and SerachItem1 and SearchItem2 specialized use cases. Both the searched are done by invoking the same web service from back-end. To design this search functionality in an enterprise application, I'm looking for good patterns. I thought of command pattern where I encapsulate different search criteria into commands. Is that a good idea? Are there any better patterns which I can follow? Appreciate if you could give me some references.

Also I need to show the search result in a paginated way. Is there any design pattern for this that I can use in combination with above?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to implement a complete freetext search functionality, the "solr" from apache is the best.

https://lucene.apache.org/solr/

Comment: I agree, buy don't build this.  There are many open source and for pay options, all better than anything you'd write yourself.

Comment: Yes, you've true. I wanted to say that there are some good solution, you don't have to write another one. I suggested solr because I use this but I give credit to 3rd and far better solution :)

Comment: Sorry, Im not asking about an enterprise search engine. I have a web service to be consumed for different types of searches, and I'm looking for good design patterns for this.

Comment: FahimFarook, The point @mig8 and I are trying to make is that if you choose a good search platform, the design patterns you are looking for will be dictated by the platform.  Lucene, for example, has extensive documentation on how to use Lucene to achieve the use cases you are asking about.